# Annotations on the API in SecurityFilterChain are blocked from controller access by swagger, only accepted by postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory

API Java - Spring Boot allows access to controllers utilizing postman, but utilizing swagger not even if both are authenticated with the correct token and validated in Azure Dicretory.
When I use annotations of the type @Component, @Service or @Configuration, SecurityFilterChain allows requests from controllers through postman, but blocks it in swagger, when removing any of these annotations the problem is reversed.

**Class: MySecurityService**

```
package br.com.xxxx.authentication.service;

import br.com.xxxx.authentication.service.abstraction.interfaces.IMySecurityService;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.web.logout.OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class MySecurityService implements IMySecurityService {

    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain clientSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2Login();
        final var logoutSuccessHandler = new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);
        logoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}");
        http.logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler));
        http.cors().disable();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/swagger*/**", "/v3/api-docs*/**", "/login/**", "/oauth2/**", "/user/login/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**Class: IMySecurityService**

```
package br.com.xxxx.authentication.service.abstraction.interfaces;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

public interface IMySecurityService {
    SecurityFilterChain clientSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) throws Exception;
}
```

**Debuging log and print-screen Postman**
[Postman call - not using anotation @Configurarion][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFNx8.png

[Postman call - using anotation @Configurarion][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwtaE.png

[Application Log][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnnG2.png

**Debuging log and print-screen Swagger**
[Returning swagger calling controller - using anotation @Configurarion][4]
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIGq0.png

**Responses**

```
Curl

curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8080/msTemplate' \
  -H 'accept: */*'
Request URL
http://localhost:8080/msTemplate
Server response
Code    Details
401
Undocumented
Error: response status is 401

Response headers
 cache-control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate 
 connection: keep-alive 
 content-length: 0 
 date: Fri,26 Jan 2024 16:09:33 GMT 
 expires: 0 
 keep-alive: timeout=60 
 pragma: no-cache 
 www-authenticate: Bearer 
 x-content-type-options: nosniff 
 x-frame-options: DENY 
 x-xss-protection: 0
```

**Thread**

```
<br>
"main@1" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at br.com.xxxx.authentication.service.MySecurityService.clientSecurityFilterChain(MySecurityService.java:40)
      at br.com.xxxx.authentication.service.MySecurityService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$clientSecurityFilterChain$0(<generated>:-1)
      at br.com.xxxx.authentication.service.MySecurityService$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>:-1)
      at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)
      at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
      at br.com.xxxx.authentication.service.MySecurityService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.clientSecurityFilterChain(<generated>:-1)
      at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/0x0000000800e18000.invokeVirtual(LambdaForm$DMH:-1)
      at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/0x000000080100c800.invoke(LambdaForm$MH:-1)
      at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/0x0000000800c02400.invokeExact_MT(LambdaForm$MH:-1)
      at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invokeImpl(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:156)
      at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:647)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$287/0x0000000800df3b40.getObject(Unknown Source:-1)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
      - locked <0x1a8c> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
      - locked <0x1a8d> (a java.lang.Object)
      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
      at br.com.xxxx.PlatformMstemplateApplication.main(PlatformMstemplateApplication.java:40)

"Catalina-utility-1@5922" prio=1 tid=0x17 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:341)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:506)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3464)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3435)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1623)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

"Catalina-utility-2@5931" prio=1 tid=0x18 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1672)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

"Common-Cleaner@6794" daemon prio=8 tid=0xd nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
      at jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(CleanerImpl.java:140)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
      at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:162)

"container-0@5946" prio=5 tid=0x19 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:-1)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:566)
      at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer$1.run(TomcatWebServer.java:197)

"Reference Handler@6790" daemon prio=10 tid=0x2 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(Reference.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(Reference.java:253)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:215)

"Finalizer@6791" daemon prio=8 tid=0x3 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:176)
      at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:183)

"Signal Dispatcher@6792" daemon prio=9 tid=0x4 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener@6793" daemon prio=5 tid=0x5 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Notification Thread@692" daemon prio=9 tid=0x11 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

[Swagger calling controller - not using anotation @Configurarion][5]
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHktn.png

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57781', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.1)

2024-01-26T12:56:48.083-03:00  INFO 74604 --- [           main] b.com.xxxx.PlatformMstemplateApplication  : Starting PlatformMstemplateApplication using Java 18.0.2.1 with PID 74604 (C:\Reconstruindo\Platform.MsTemplate.Java\target\classes started by 4960000083 in C:\Reconstruindo\Platform.MsTemplate.Java)
2024-01-26T12:56:48.089-03:00  INFO 74604 --- [           main] b.com.xxxx.PlatformMstemplateApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-01-26T12:56:50.445-03:00  INFO 74604 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=e197ce10-f929-386d-a01e-9b5a9061e13f
2024-01-26T12:56:51.076-03:00  INFO 74604 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2024-01-26T12:56:51.087-03:00  INFO 74604 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-01-26T12:56:51.088-03:00  INFO 74604 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.10]
2024-01-26T12:56:51.287-03:00  INFO 74604 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-01-26T12:56:51.290-03:00  INFO 74604 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3054 ms
2024-01-26T12:57:05.845-03:00 ERROR 74604 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] Retira.MsTemplate                        : executando controller
{"@timestamp":"2024-01-26T12:57:05.8453726-03:00","@version":"1","message":"executando controller","logger_name":"Retira.MsTemplate","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-8","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"CONSOLE_LOG_THRESHOLD":"TRACE","FILE_LOG_PATTERN":"%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX} %5p 74604 --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n%wEx","FILE_LOG_CHARSET":"UTF-8","PID":"74604","CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN":"%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(74604){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wEx","FILE_LOG_THRESHOLD":"TRACE","CONSOLE_LOG_CHARSET":"UTF-8"}
2024-01-26T12:57:05.853-03:00 ERROR 74604 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] Retira.MsTemplate                        : executando repositotory
{"@timestamp":"2024-01-26T12:57:05.8533763-03:00","@version":"1","message":"executando repositotory","logger_name":"Retira.MsTemplate","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-8","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"CONSOLE_LOG_THRESHOLD":"TRACE","FILE_LOG_PATTERN":"%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX} %5p 74604 --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n%wEx","FILE_LOG_CHARSET":"UTF-8","PID":"74604","CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN":"%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(74604){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wEx","FILE_LOG_THRESHOLD":"TRACE","CONSOLE_LOG_CHARSET":"UTF-8"}
2024-01-26T12:57:06.533-03:00 ERROR 74604 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] Retira.MsTemplate                        : finalizando repositotory
{"@timestamp":"2024-01-26T12:57:06.5333754-03:00","@version":"1","message":"finalizando repositotory","logger_name":"Retira.MsTemplate","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-8","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"CONSOLE_LOG_THRESHOLD":"TRACE","FILE_LOG_PATTERN":"%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX} %5p 74604 --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n%wEx","FILE_LOG_CHARSET":"UTF-8","PID":"74604","CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN":"%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(74604){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wEx","FILE_LOG_THRESHOLD":"TRACE","CONSOLE_LOG_CHARSET":"UTF-8"}
```

When removing any of these annotations the problem is reversed, starting to accept requests from the controller through swagger only.

The error that has been occurring is HTTP 401

Answer (score 1):

When you remove annotation `@Configuration` you simply disable security you have configured in class. Without `@Configuration` annotation `Spring` cannot find your `MySecurityService` with `SecurityFilterChain` configuration. That is why behaviour changes.

You make requests from postman with Authorisation, it is visible on [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwtaE.png).

You need to make call from swagger with authorisation as well, in another case you will receive **401** response, that means your are not authorised, it is visible on [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIGq0.png).

Spring boot does not care through what client you make a call. Behaviour is vary because you have different requests.

Comment: completely agree, he is comparing apples to oranges and then wondering why they are different